# egrep outputs everything instead of only the lines matching the patterns from list

Tags: grep

I have used egrep in the past succesfully, typically using the following

`egrep -f list_of_patterns big_file_to_look_for_patterns > selected_patterns_from_big_file`

however, I ve been trying this morning to do the same but I constantly get everything as output -> not only the patterns I provide through the list but the entire file I was looking from

files can be found here: https://filebin.net/ibovbjy68x4a8kez

list of patterns: "allMAGs_list_85_5_list"

big_file_to_look_for_patterns: "goodfile"

based on a previous post by someone having a similar problem with grep I tried `tr '\r' '\n'` to eliminate carriage but that did not help...

thanks in advance

Comment: If your pattern file does not actually contain regex patterns, but fixed strings, use `grep -F -w -f patterns file...`

Comment: To remove carriage returns, remove them: `tr -d '\r'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First a note: `egrep` is deprecated and could be removed at some point, use `grep -E` instead. Now your problem is that your file of patterns contains empty lines. As a result, grep is looking for an empty string which is found in all lines so returns all results. You can see the same thing here:

```
$ seq 10 | grep "" 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Just remove the empty lines from your file and try again:

```
sed '/^$/d' allMAGs_list_85_5_list > fixed.list
grep -Ef fixed.list goodfile
```

You can also fix the original list file with

```
sed -i '/^$/d' allMAGs_list_85_5_list
```

or do it on the fly with

```
grep -Ef <(sed '/^$/d' allMAGs_list_85_5_list) goodfile
```